# Alternative ideas for INTO CLAUSE in DYNAMIC SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, cobol

I just learned,I will not able to use `INTO CLAUSE` in stored procedure,while using dynamic sql.

Below is my Dynamic SQL.

```
SET V_SELECT =                   
  'SELECT ' || SELECT_FIELDS ||    
  ' FROM '  || TABLE_NAME    ||  
  ' WHERE ' || WHERE_CLAUSE  ||  
  ' WITH UR';    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT;
```

requirement to use the procedure for multiple queries.

This is how my queries looks a like after passing values.

```
  SELECT B.PROD_TYP,
          A.PROD_LINE,
          B.PROD_TXT,
          B.PROD_TXT1
   FROM TABLE_A   A
   INNER JOIN TABLE_B  B
   ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
   WHERE A.PROD_CD = HOST_VAR_PROD_CD;
```

I have to return the `SELECT` fields.How do I return value of these fields.These fields and table and query will change.

Comment: **Avoid** dynamic SQL, it will create to many problems. If you must you could save the results in a table and then retrieve them using static SQL. You will need to create a unique key which you can use to do the insert the values, retrieve and then delete them

Comment: @BruceMartin what kind of problems do you anticipate with dynamic SQL?

Comment: @Prabhu Have you considered studying the sample programs in the Db2 Knowledge Centre to get basic comprehension about cursor usage? It can be more effective than asking duplicate questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @mao, Thanks for the advice. I know how to build CURSOR and basic about DB2. I'm new to Stored procedure. I'm looking for right way to do the dynamic select.I don't see this as duplicate questions. I'm just try to put my question in a better way. I'm sorry, that you felt its annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code and it working fine. I was able to run multiple select's using Dynamic.

```
DECLARE DESC_CSR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR V_SQL;  

  SET V_SELECT =                              
  'SELECT ' || SELECT_FIELDS ||               
  ' FROM '  || TABLE_NAME    ||               
  ' WHERE ' || WHERE_CLAUSE  ||               
  ' WITH UR';                                 


  PREPARE V_SQL FROM V_SELECT;  

  OPEN DESC_CSR USING HOST_VAR_B;

  FETCH DESC_CSR INTO HOST_VAR_A;
```

I pass parm as below. using the where clause HOST_VAR_B as Parameter marker "?" and assigning the field at OPEN.

```
SELECT_FIELDS = B.COLUMN_A  INTO HOST_VAR_A
TABLE_NAME =  TABLE_A A   INNER JOIN TABLE_B B      
              ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
WHERE_CLAUSE = A.COLUMN_B = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic example of how to use dynamic sql & cursors.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_STMT VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE V_CREATOR VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE V_NAME VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE V_COLCOUNT INT;
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);

  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;

  SET V_CREATOR = 'SYSIBM';
  SET V_STMT = 'SELECT NAME, COLCOUNT FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES WHERE CREATOR = ?';
  PREPARE S1 FROM V_STMT;
  OPEN C1 USING V_CREATOR;
  L1: LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO V_NAME, V_COLCOUNT;
    IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
    --Some processing here
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
END
@
```

Answer (score 0):

On Db2 for IBM i at least,

`values into` can be dynamically prepared and run and thus used in place of `select into`

You will need to know how many columns are being returned...

```
SET V_SELECT =                   
  'values (SELECT ' || SELECT_FIELDS ||    
  ' FROM '  || TABLE_NAME    ||  
  ' WHERE ' || WHERE_CLAUSE  ||  
  ' ) into ?,?,?' ||
  ' WITH UR';    

Prepare wSelect from :V_SELECT;
//should be checking SQLSTATE/SQLCODE here for errors

execute wSelect using :col1, :col2, col3;
//should be checking SQLSTATE/SQLCODE here for errors
```

If the number of columns returned are dynamic, you might consider using the `LISTAGG()` function if available to return a comma delimited string with all the values in a single column.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Now I ran into something else. But have no idea how to handle it. Hope somebody can help. I'm using || WHERE_CLAUSE || as parameter. after passing value it will look like ' WHERE A.COLUMN_B = HOST_VAR_B' My execute fails with HOST_VAR_B is not acceptable in WHERE. If I pass where as 'WHERE A.COLUMN_B = 101' with actual HOST_VAR_B. Its working fine. But I will not able to Hard code the HOST_VAR_B value since it will have to pass the HOST_VAR_B from program.

Comment: you'll need to concat the contents of your host variable, or use a parameter marker

Comment: It's working fine with the Parameter marker. Thank you so much for your help.